# How can I migrate websites between two identical servers?

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, web-server, migration

I have two servers that have a nearly identical (software) configuration. We are upgrading the web servers to run windows server 2008 R2, one already is however the main one (that currently has sites) is on WS2008.

Now, the old server is ns.mydomain.com and the new server is ns1.mydomain.com. Since dns automatically fails over to ns1.mydomain.com I'd like a way to move all the vhosts to the new server.

Is there an automatic way to move / recreate all the vhosts on the new server?

I have figured out how to migrate the DNS records already [DNS Migration](http://blogger.xs4all.nl/zanstra/archive/2004/11/26/windnsbackup.aspx) and since both servers are on the same private network migrating the website data isn't a large issue. Every site is running PHP & MySQL and the MySQL server is external so the records won't have to be moved.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [IIS Web Deployment tool](http://www.iis.net/download/webdeploy), that should get you started with migrating the IIS sites and settings.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you just clone the server by using tool like clonezilla, which makes it much easier to do